# How to get the first name in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

How to get the First Name Friend

But here I want to take the first name even though its input there is a last name with spaces

Example : 
First friend

I Input the name : Alvin Indra

Second Friend

I Input the name : Redi Rusmana

And output :

Alvin

Redi

Please help me 
Syntax :

```
package latihan;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LatihanArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int many;
        String[] friend = new String[100];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scx = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter How Many Friends : ");
        many = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print("Friend Of-"+(i+1)+" : ");
            friend[i] = scx.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("Initials : ");
        for(int i=0;i<many;i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+". "+friend[i].charAt(0));
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("4 Letterhead : ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+". "+friend[i].substring(0,4));
        }
        System.out.println("First Name : ");
        for(??????){
            if(??????){
               for(????????){
                  ???????????????;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `String.indexOf()` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)) to locate the first space, and `String.substring()` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)) to pull out the first name.

Comment: System.out.println("First Name : ");
        for(??????){
            if(??????){
               for(????????){
                  ???????????????;
               }
            }
        }

where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter friend's name as a string `"<firstName> <lastName>"` (with space symbol between parts). In case you want to store it as one String, you can use following methods:

1. Regular expression: `(?<firstName>\w+)\s+(?<lastName>\w+)` and get both parts directly
2. Split string with space: `String[] parts = friend.split("\s+")` and get `parts[0]` as first name, and `parts[1]` as last name
3. But I strongly recommend you to use special class to store input data, because in general case, if you need post processing, it is much better to prepare all data for it. I give you simple example to show id. You could look at it and maybe use it with some corrections (because I do not know your requirements):

Friend data holder

```
final class Friend {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Friend(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getInitials() {
        return String.valueOf(firstName.charAt(0)) + lastName.charAt(0);
    }

    public String getLetterHead() {
        return firstName.substring(0, 4);
    }
}
```

Method to read and print data (from your question)

```
List<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter How Many Friends : ");
int many = scan.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < many; i++) {
    System.out.print("Friend Of-" + (i + 1) + " : ");
    String firstName = scan.next();
    String lastName = scan.next();
    friends.add(new Friend(i + 1, firstName, lastName));
}

scan.close();

System.out.println("\nInitials: ");
for (Friend friend : friends)
    System.out.println(String.format("%d. %s", friend.id, friend.getInitials()));

System.out.println("\n4 Letterhead: ");
for (Friend friend : friends)
    System.out.println(String.format("%d. %s", friend.id, friend.getLetterHead()));

System.out.println("\nFirst Name: ");
for (Friend friend : friends)
    System.out.println(String.format("%d. %s", friend.id, friend.firstName));

System.out.println("\nLast Name: ");
for (Friend friend : friends)
    System.out.println(String.format("%d. %s", friend.id, friend.lastName));
    }
}
```

As result you see following in console:

```
Enter How Many Friends : 2
Friend Of-1 : Alvin Indra
Friend Of-2 : Redi Rusmana

Initials: 
1. AI
2. RR

4 Letterhead: 
1. Alvi
2. Redi

First Name: 
1. Alvin
2. Redi

Last Name: 
1. Indra
2. Rusmana
```